# Creating mock cloud kit objects for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, swift, cloudkit

Trying to mock CKDatabase but it has no accessible initializer. Is there another way to create a fake CKDatabase object?

This code comes back with the "error: cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable"

```
class MockDatabase : CKDatabase
{
    override func saveRecord(record: CKRecord!, completionHandler: ((CKRecord!, NSError!) -> Void)!) { }

    override func deleteRecordWithID(recordID: CKRecordID!, completionHandler: ((CKRecordID!, NSError!) -> Void)!) { }

    override func fetchRecordWithID(recordID: CKRecordID!, completionHandler: ((CKRecord!, NSError!) -> Void)!) { }

    override func deleteSubscriptionWithID(subscriptionID: String!, completionHandler: ((String!, NSError!) -> Void)!) { }

    override func saveSubscription(subscription: CKSubscription!, completionHandler: ((CKSubscription!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {}
}
```

The cloud kit framework seems like a perfect candidate for unit testing as there are a lot of possible errors that can come back from the server and making sure your app can handle them all consistently , with every iteration would be great. Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: My newest thought is to create an protocol extension of CKDatabase with my own wrapper methods to CKDatabase methods. Since my object would be a Protocol instance of unknown class type I could then mock an object of that protocol. Phew. Maybe to much spaghetti here.

Comment: After a quick look it seems like a MockProtocolExtension is totally doable if not completely insane. A lot of extra boiler plate. In the midst of this code I've realized that since CKDatabase takes so many completionHandlers: I could just have these completion handlers be methods of my class (somehow) and call these methods with my unit tests. I'd never mock CKDatabase but I would call the completion handlers/methods in my unit tests making sure I aped all the possible returns I could get from CKDatabase.

Comment: To bad that it is still impossible to have such CKDatabase objects available for testing. Did you succeed in calling the completion handlers instead?

Answer (score 1):

Since CKDatabase init is made unavailable, you will never be able to create an instance of it. So there is no point in creating your MockDatabase because you will never be able to create an instance of that. The only way to do some sort of Mocking is by creating your own DAO class wrapper around the CKDatabase functionality and only call CKDatabase functions using that DAO. Then you could mock that DAO. You could even add extra functionality to that DAO, but then you will not be able to test that.

Comment: If you need help setting up such a DAO, then have a look at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao I does have some extra functionality so I don't think it completely right for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out. I'm assuming then you don't do unit testing for the Cloud Kit portion in that framework but mock your DAO object only.

Comment: So far I only test the DAO itself using one big integration test. Besides that for my usage there is not much point in creating an extra layer that needs to be tested. The DAO code is so easy and compact you will have only a couple of lines of code in your view controller. I test that using calabash. So it's more of an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

All the CloudKit classes are `@objc` (they all derive from NSObject.) That means they use dynamic dispatching. In Objective-C you could mock CKDatabase by implementing a new Obj-C class MockCKDatabase that subclasses NSObject and implements all the public methods of CKDatabase (or at least all the ones you use.) Then you literally just instantiate one and cast the pointer from `MockCKDatabase*` to `CKDatabase*`.

I've never done this sort of thing in Swift, but I imagine that if you just did the same steps it should work.

Answer (score 0):

as @Edwin pointed out, CKDatabase init is made unavailable, so you can't make instances of it. Neither can you subclass or use an extension to override CKContainer init (compiler will complain that 'init()' is unavailable). You can't even use a CKContainer with a mock of CKDatabase, since the logic that associates them is hidden within the CloudKit implementation. All that said, I built a framework called MockCloudKitFramework that is a drop-in replacement for a limited (but reasonable) subset of CloudKit capabilities. The [MockCloudKitFramework (MCF)](https://github.com/ccavnor/MockCloudKitTesting) implements mock operations for CKContainer and CKDatabase, plus the main subclasses of CKDatabaseOperation.

MCF creates its own protocols (that contain the same signatures as their CloudKit counterparts) and extends both CloudKit and MCF mocks from this set of protocols. It was necessary to create these protocols since CKContainer and CKDatabase both inherit directly from NSObject as their common Protocol. So that IOC would force generic functions to be open to NSObject types - leaving functions wide open for injection of everything that inherits from NSObject.

So using MCF comes down to:

1. Extending CloudKit and MCF classes from these protocols.
2. Refactoring your code to use generics - typed on the MCF protocols.
3. Using IOC to inject the mocks of CKContainer and CKDatabase (MockCKContainer and MockCKDatabase, respectively).

See the MCF docs - examples are provided, along with unit and integration tests.

##### Using MCF

Lets say that you have a generic class that takes a type based on the CKContainerProtocol protocol (one of the MCF protocols). It contains a method that accepts either a CKFetchRecordsOperation or a MockCKFetchRecordsOperation (the MCF mock of CKFetchRecordsOperation) based on their common MCF protocol, CKFetchRecordsOperationProtocol:

```swift
import CloudKit

/// Example Class to handle iCloud related transactions. 
class CloudController<T: CKContainerProtocol> {
    let cloudContainer: T
    let database: T.DatabaseType

    init(container: T, databaseScope: CKDatabase.Scope) {
        self.cloudContainer = container
        self.database = container.database(with: databaseScope)
    }

    /// Check if a record exists in iCloud.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - cKFetchRecordsOperation: the fetch operation
    ///   - recordId: the record id to locate
    ///   - completion: closure to execute on caller
    /// - Returns: success(true) when record is located,  success(false) when record is not found, failure if an error occurred.
    func checkCloudRecordExists<O: CKFetchRecordsOperationProtocol> (
            cKFetchRecordsOperation: O,
            recordId: CKRecord.ID,
            _ completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {
                var dbOperation = cKFetchRecordsOperation
                dbOperation.recordIDs = [recordId]
                var record: CKRecord?
                dbOperation.desiredKeys = ["recordID"]
                // perRecordResultBlock doesn't get called if the record doesn't exist
                dbOperation.perRecordResultBlock = { _, result in
                    // success iff no partial failure
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let r):
                        record = r
                    case .failure:
                        record = nil
                    }
                }
                // fetchRecordsResultBlock always gets called when finished processing.
                dbOperation.fetchRecordsResultBlock = { result in
                    // success if no transaction error
                    switch result {
                    case .success:
                        if let _ = record { // record exists and no errors
                            completion(.success(true))
                        } else { // record does not exist
                            completion(.success(false))
                        }
                    case .failure(let error): // either transaction or partial failure occurred
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }

                database.add(dbOperation)
            }
}
```

We can build a test without MCF that validates that the record does (or doesn't) exist, but first we have to:

1. Populate (or depopulate) the CloudKit test environment with the data to set the test up.
2. Make sure that we are using the same CKDatabase scope (public, private, or shared) as where the data is.
3. Hope that there are no network hiccups or data transfer errors that will inject unanticipated errors or interruptions.

But still, we can't test what the error conditions might be since we have no control over them.

MCF allows us to test all of this, using a local mock instance of CKDatabase (MockCKDatabase) that we can manipulate directly or through CloudKit modification operations like (Mock)CKModifyRecordsOperation. MockCKContainer is used to access the MockCKDatabase instance of the appropriate scope using the same accessors as CKContainer does. Here is an example of a test case setup:

```swift
import XCTest
import CloudKit
@testable import OurProject // required for access to CloudController
import MockCloudKitFramework // import MCF only into test environment

class MockCloudKitTestProjectIntegrationTest: XCTestCase {
    var cloudContainer: MockCKContainer!
    var cloudDatabase: MockCKDatabase!
    // NOTE that CloudController class is a Generic and that both CKContainer and MockCKContainer extend CKContainerProtocol
    var cloudController: CloudController<MockCKContainer>!

    // called before each test
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        try? super.setUpWithError()
        // reset state for each test. Each test must set up exactly the state they require.
        MockCKContainer.resetContainer()
        // get the default container from MCF
        cloudContainer = MockCKContainer.default()
        // get the MockCKDatabase of CKDatabase.Scope of private
        cloudDatabase = cloudContainer.privateCloudDatabase
        // we pass in a MockCKContainer to the generic function expecting a class that extends MCF CKContainerProtocol
        cloudController = CloudController(container: cloudContainer, databaseScope: .private)
    }
}
```

Now we can test the checkCloudRecordExists() method by adding the record that we expect to fetch directly to MockCKDatabase and calling the function, passing in our mock CKFetchRecordsOperation:

```swift
func test_checkCloudRecordExists_success() {
    let expect = expectation(description: "CKDatabase fetch")
    let record = makeCKRecord() // function that makes a CKRecord
    // add the record to MockCKDatabase
    cloudDatabase.addRecords(records: [record])
    let operation = MockCKFetchRecordsOperation()
    // pass in our mock CKFetchRecordsOperation
    cloudController.checkCloudRecordExists(cKFetchRecordsOperation: operation, recordId: record.recordID) { exists in
        XCTAssertTrue(exists)
        expect.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
}
```

If we wanted to test an error condition from the call, we just need to add an error using the setError property of MockCKDatabaseOperation (or any of its subclasses). Now the test will fail, even though the record exists. This simulates an internal error that was the result of a CloudKit transaction:

```swift
// call checkCloudRecordExists() when the record is present but error is set
func test_checkCloudRecordExists_error() {
    let expect = expectation(description: "CKDatabase fetch")
    let record = makeCKRecord()
    cloudDatabase.addRecords(records: [record])
    let operation = MockCKFetchRecordsOperation()
    // set an error on operation
    let nsErr = createNSError(with: CKError.Code.internalError)
    operation.setError = nsErr
    cloudController.checkCloudRecordExists(cKFetchRecordsOperation: operation, recordId: record.recordID) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            XCTFail("should have failed")
            expect.fulfill()
        case .failure(let error):
            XCTAssertEqual(error.createCKError().code.rawValue, nsErr.code)
            expect.fulfill()
        }
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
}
```

We can even test our function logic for [partial failures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerror/2325226-partialfailure) to make sure that we handle the scenario of when a record *might* be found but some CKError occurred so we cannot be sure. All we need to do is set the setRecordErrors property on the operation to the set of record ids that should fail (MCF picks a random CKError to fail with):

```swift
// test for partial failures
    func test_checkCloudRecordExists_partial_failure() {
        let expect = expectation(description: "CKDatabase fetch")
        let record = makeCKRecord()
        cloudDatabase.addRecords(records: [record])
        let operation = MockCKFetchRecordsOperation()
        // set an error on operation
        operation.setRecordErrors = [record.recordID]
        cloudController.checkCloudRecordExists(cKFetchRecordsOperation: operation, recordId: record.recordID) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                XCTFail("should have failed")
            case .failure(let error):
                let ckError = error.createCKError()
                XCTAssertEqual(ckError.code.rawValue,
                               CKError.partialFailure.rawValue,
                               "The transaction error should always be set to CKError.partialFailure when record errors occur")
                if let partialErr: NSDictionary = error.createCKError().getPartialErrors() {
                    let ckErr = partialErr.allValues.first as? CKError
                    XCTAssertEqual("CKErrorDomain", ckErr?.toNSError().domain)
                    expect.fulfill()
                }
            }
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
    }
```

Comment: @matt Thanks for the guidance. I added some examples of how mock testing might be accomplished.

Comment: @matt Thanks very much for the guidance Matt. I took your input into account and revised both the codebase and the posting. MockCloudkitFramework now uses protocol extensions (the user must copy these into test and project targets and extend using the documented extensions). But other than that, only IOC is required (using generics so as to type against the protocols that MockCloudkitFramework provides).